# Using Mixer with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, testing, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use [mixer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mixer/2.1.0) to generate test data for a website powered by Flask+SQLAlchemy.

I have created a file called `generate_test_data.py` in the root directory of my project that looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import app
from mixer.backend.flask import mixer
from models import *

def generate_test_data():
        user = mixer.blend(Users)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        generate_test_data()
```

Yet, every time I run the file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_test_data.py", line 3, in <module>
    import app
ImportError: No module named app
```

I am doing this with the correct virtualenv activated.

**Update**

My project structure looks like this:

```
/
 - generate_test_data.py
 - app/
 -- __init__.py
 -- models.py
```

** Update**

My `__init__.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.uwsgi_websocket import GeventWebSocket
from config import REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT
import redis


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ws = GeventWebSocket(app)

POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=0)
redis = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)

from app import views, models
```

Comment: can you share the `__init__.py` code ? How are you instantiating the flask app itself ? I am guessing your project folder is named app/ while your flask application is also called app. Some conflict happening. Better to rename project folder like say "myapp" and then do "from myapp import app"

Comment: Added the code to my `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-structure your project strucuture as:

```
myproject/
    generate_test_data.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
```

Then, in your `generate_test_data.py`, you can just do

```
from myproject import app
```

This will be better because you are removing any name conflicts. Also, you are explicitly importing your app variable which you really want. You can of course name "myproject" to whatever you want but don't name it "app" to be safe