# How to import module from folder

Tags: python, module, python-import

Following my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510602/using-mixer-with-flask-sqlalchemy/22512224) question, how can I import a module that is in a folder at the same level as the file importing it? I need to get to my models folder but importing it isn't working:

```
$ python generate_test_data.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_test_data.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import *
ImportError: No module named models
Exception KeyError: KeyError(48562256,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
/
 - generate_test_data.py
 - app/
 -- __init__.py
 -- models.py
```

Comment: can you post a tree of relevant folders?

Comment: @m.wasowski - check my previous answer.

Comment: @Cocoaster: No, please post it here; questions should be able to stand on their own.

Comment: Done, although I think not by me.

Comment: I've added the structure *from your question* here. If that doesn't reflect your current setup, please do update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from app.models import *
```

should do the trick

Comment: You generally shouldn't `import *`. It is considered bad practice as it will go wrong if two imported modules use two of the same function or class names and Python will not know which. It is generally better to do something like `import app.models as mdls`.

Comment: Your argument is valid for production, but: 1) thats what OP asked for 2) names indicate that it is for testing, not production code, 3) It looks like very early stage of development.